# saving word2vec in text format

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I tried to save word2vec vector as text, but it didnt work out, I got an error, that I dont really understand, what duplicates appear here and what is this "wv", that is proposed. Maybe somone can explain is to me. Thank you in advance

```
model = Word2Vec(all_words, min_count=3, sg = 1, size = 300 )
model.save_word2vec_format('test_w2v.txt', binary=False)
```

```
WARNING:gensim.models.base_any2vec:under 10 jobs per worker: consider setting a smaller `batch_words' for smoother alpha decay
Word2Vec(vocab=20, size=300, alpha=0.025)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/word2vec.py", line 26, in <module>
    model.save_word2vec_format('test_w2v.txt', binary=False)
  File "/word2vec.py", line 1307, in save_word2vec_format
    raise DeprecationWarning("Deprecated. Use model.wv.save_word2vec_format instead.")
DeprecationWarning: Deprecated. Use model.wv.save_word2vec_format instead.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `.save_word2vec_format()` only saves the vectors – not the full model – it should only be used on the sub-property `.wv` of the model. (That's an object that just contains the vectors.)

So, if you run `model.wv.save_word2vec_format('test_w2v.txt', binary=False)`, as recommended by the error message, you'll save the vectors in text format.

(If you need to save the full model, use `model.save()` - it will save more information, and possibly use multiple additional files, but it will be in a Python- and gensim-specific format, unlike the plain text format that other tools can read.)

Comment: thank you a lot. maybe you also know what write_first_line do as a parameter?

Comment: You're welcome! I suggest you check the docs –  https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.Word2VecKeyedVectors.save_word2vec_format – or simply try a save both with and without that parameter, on a tiny model, to see exactly what it does. (It may not even be available as a parameter, on the specific, `Word2Vec`-based word-vectors you're working with.)

Comment: @gojomo when I try `model.wv.save_word2vec_format('test_w2v.txt', binary=False)` it throws `UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\ud83c' in position 0: surrogates not allowed` error as the vocabulary contains emojis. Any other suggestions on how to save the same vectors in text format?

Comment: @AbuShoeb You should ask separate questions, with different error messages, in separate StackOverflow questions, with the full code & error message.